# Full image from camera intent

Tags: android

I am using camera and want to get the full image from bitmap. Currently I have a bitmap size of thumbnail so when I try to scale it, the image looks blurry and stretched. I am also saving the image in my app folder on sdcard. How can I get a full size image from bitmap?
Thanks

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);


 if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

// I have tried scaling and using matrix but doesn't makes the quality of image any better

```
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(612, 936, Config.ARGB_8888);

              float scaleX = 612 / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
              float scaleY = 936 / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
              float pivotX = 0;
              float pivotY = 0;

              Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
              scaleMatrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotX, pivotY);

              Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
              canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);

              Paint paint = new Paint();
              paint.setAntiAlias(true);
              paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
              paint.setDither(true);

              canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
String picturePath = "/path";
File imageFile = new File(picturePath);
Uri imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```